# How to pass multiple string values from Http.PutAsJsonAsync in Blazor app

Tags: c#, html, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I need to Post two string values to add a company in DB. Here I have written PUT as

```
 await Http.PutAsJsonAsync($"api/B2CUsers/company/invitation/add/{UtpID}/{User.email}",UtpID,User.email);
```

I get an error at  `User.email` which says `cannot convert string to System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions`.

controller function:

```
[HttpPut("company/invitation/add/{utpid}/{emailAddressInvitedUser}")]
        public async Task<int> AddUserCompanyInvitationAsync(string utpid, string emailAddressInvitedUser)
        {
            string userid = GetCurrentUser();
            return await _iB2CUserServiceRepository.AddUserCompanyInvitation(userid, utpid, emailAddressInvitedUser);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: It is customary to pass a single value to a Web Api end point, so you'd better define a single DTO object which will contain the values of both strings, something like this:

```
var dtoObj = new DtoObject  { UtpID = UtpID, Email = User.email };
       
 using var response = 
    await htpClient.PutAsJsonAsync("api/B2CUsers/company/invitation/add", 
                                                            dtoObj );
 response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

Note: Your code should define an object named DtoObject that is scoped to your Web Api and Blazor (Perhaps you can put it in the Shared project ?)

In the AddUserCompanyInvitationAsync Web Api method, you'll get a single parameter object of type DtoObject, which you can use it in your code like this:

```
 return await
_iB2CUserServiceRepository.AddUserCompanyInvitation(userid, dtoObj.UtpID , dtoObj.Email);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried something like merged 2 strings into a list of string. Passed that to controller and divided in controller. It kinda helped me pass as single block of values. Yeah something like your way. Find it easy. So selecting this as answer & +1

Answer (score 1):

Correct function signature is

```
[HttpGet("company/invitation/add2/{utpid}/{emailAddressInvitedUser}")]
public Task<int> AddUserCompanyInvitationAsync([FromRoute] string utpid, [FromRoute] string emailAddressInvitedUser)
```

If you don't add [FromRoute] attributes .NET will not map route values to your variables.

Keep in mind this kind of request will be logged in the web serveur log's. This mean email addresses will be visible in the logs. You also need to escape the email string with [HttpUtility.UrlEncode](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.urlencode?view=net-5.0)

> curl -X PUT "http://localhost:14786/company/invitation/add2/45/test%40test.com" -H  "accept: text/plain"

The prefered way to do that is to pass Json request in the body.

```
public class AddUserRequest
{
    public int utpid { get; set; }
    public string emailAddressInvitedUser { get; set; }
}

public class AddUserResponse
{
    public int uid { get; set; }
}
[HttpPut("company/invitation/add1")]
public Task<AddUserResponse> AddUserCompanyInvitationAsync([FromBody]AddUserRequest addUserRequest)
{
    Console.WriteLine(addUserRequest.utpid);
    Console.WriteLine(addUserRequest.emailAddressInvitedUser);
    return Task.FromResult(new AddUserResponse() { uid = 1 });
}
```

and for the client

```
var client = new HttpClient();
int id = 45;
string email = "test@test.com";
await client.GetAsync($"http://localhost:14786/company/invitation/add2/{id}/{System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(email)}");

var response = await client.PutAsJsonAsync("http://localhost:14786/company/invitation/add1", new AddUserRequest() { utpid = id, emailAddressInvitedUser = email });
```

Instead of PUT use POST